# UIScrollView, button click is not working...

Tags: iphone, scrollview

I am using the sample code, PageControl from iOS Developer Library.

What I want to do is

1) add a button in MyView.xib
 2) if the button is clicked go to page 2

So, this is what I did.

1) Created a button in MyView.xib
2) Created IBAction in "MyViewController.m" like

```
 - (IBAction)toPageTwo:(id)sender;

    {

        NSLog(@"button clicked...");
        PhoneContentController * callSview = [[PhoneContentController alloc] init];
        [callSview showPage:2];

    }
```

Then, Created following method in PhoneContentController.m to go to page two.

```
- (void)showPage:(int)page;

{

    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*(page -1), 0) animated:YES];    
    NSLog(@"Method called..and the scrollview width is %f  ", scrollView.frame.size.width);
    //prints negative value or 0.000. why?

}
```

***Problem***

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*(page -1), 0) animated:YES];
```

does not work if button is clicked.
(It is working fine, if showPage is called within PhoneContentController.m)

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you connected the button to the IBAction outlet in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in:

```
- (IBAction)toPageTwo:(id)sender;
{
   NSLog(@"button clicked...");
   PhoneContentController * callSview = [[PhoneContentController alloc] init];
   [callSview showPage:2];
```

you have no need to allocate a new `PhoneContentController`, since you are already in your main `PhoneContentController`. Simply send `showPage` message to `self`.

```
- (IBAction)toPageTwo:(id)sender;
{
   NSLog(@"button clicked...");
   [self showPage:2];
```

This is just a guess, since I do not know exactly to which class your method belog (but I guess it is `PhoneContentController`).